# Bluetooth application in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate using C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bluetooth, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I have seen many links that talk about 32feet.NET library.  I need to know how to use this in C#.  Pretty much everything uses Visual Basic but I am not too familiar with that language.  I do prefer to do it C#.  As additional information, the application will be sending data similar to a serial interface.  This means that it will be sending bytes to a device that will respond with bytes as well.  I am trying to use the built-in bluetooth but I cannot find the port associated with that nor am I able to detect it using other examples online, I have tried the Power Shell example as well.

Answer (score 1):

The thinking was when I wrote the documentation was that there were a lot of VB users using the library, and that all C# users would be able to *read* the VB code, even if they weren't able to *write* VB themselves.  See http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Visual%20Basic%20Samples for some help.

Have a go at looking at the examples and see if you can pick out the real code in there -- I myself find it hard to ignore the **If**, **Then**, **End** etc words but can manage it.  I've just updated the main pages to include C# versions of the samples, when I have some more free time I'll do some more. :-)